# Why doesn't kcachegrind display the call graph?

Tags: linux, kcachegrind

I am trying to get some information about the flow of a large program. KCachegrind used to be great for this in the past. But the latest version (0.6kde) I have on my system (Kubuntu 10.10) won't display the call tree and caller map. It only draws a box with the current function, but no arrows and no callers. Here's the console output:

```
kcachegrind(27917)/kdecore (services) KMimeTypeFactory::parseMagic: Now parsing  "/usr/share/mime/magic"
QInotifyFileSystemWatcherEngine::addPaths: inotify_add_watch failed: No such file or directory
QFileSystemWatcher: failed to add paths: /home/cosmin/.config/ibus/bus
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon 
CallGraphView::refresh 
CallGraphView::refresh: Started process 0x1346f50, 'dot -Tplain'
CallGraphView::readDotOutput: QProcess 0x1346f50
CallGraphView::dotExited: QProcess 0x1346f50
```

I have dot (graphviz) installed, and the application was compiled with -g -O0.

Do you have any idea where the problem could be?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Oops... I was calling `valgrind --tool=cachegrind` instead of `valgrind --tool=callgrind`.

Comment: awesome just made the same exact mistake!

Comment: well the name doesn't do justice too - k**cache**grind.

Comment: I find it rather amusing that I could find that answer on StacOverflow. I just made the exact same mistake.

Comment: Turns out not only does graphviz's dot application need to be installed, one also needs to run "dot -c" after installation, as root, to configure stuff.